# What does f.write << TEMPLATE mean in the below code snippet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
File.open("db/quotes/#{id}.json", "w") do |f|
          f.write <<TEMPLATE
          {
            "submitter": "{hash["submitter"]}",
            "quote": "{hash["quote"]}",
            "attribution": "{hash["attribution"]}"
          }
          TEMPLATE
end
```

I understand what this method is doing. I read this code snippet out of a book. It is trying to write to a json to a file with whatever name #{id}.json is. I have never seen it before. Is "<<" an operator? What is "TEMPLATE"? Btw, this it out of the book rebuilding ruby on rails. In the section of rebuilding the Model layer is where i found the code snippet. It could have something to do with the Gem "erubis".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f.write` expects a string as an argument and writes that string to the file `f`.

`<<TEMPLATE` starts a string that ends at the next occurrence of `TEMPLATE`. This kind of strings are called [heredocs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents).

Answer (score 2):

It's `here-document` syntax for string. It's a way to represent a string spanning multiple lines and the indentation will be preserved.

```
str = <<EOF
this will be the content
of your string
EOF
```

You can choose whatever word you want where I put EOF.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers point you in the right direction of [heredocs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents).

Technically this is syntax error with the string never terminating.

```
begin
  str = <<EOS
    This is my string
    EOS
end
```

Because the `EOS` at the beginning of the line. The below example works:

```
begin
  str = <<EOS
    This is my string
EOS
end
```

To have correctly indented code you would do the following:

```
begin
  str = <<-EOS
    This is my string
  EOS
end
```